# Django Model for associating Favourites

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Use case:
Want to let an admin create favourite relationships between users.
To do this, I am creating a model called Favourites.

```
class Favourite(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    otheruser = models.IntegerField()
```

However, both user and otherusers are both objects in CustomUsers. In the admin console, when adding a favourite I get a list of users, but I do not get a list of other users obviously.

What model field can I use so that when adding a favourite I get a list of users, and when choosing the otheruser that is also a list of users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes more sense here to add a [**`ManyToManyField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) in your `CustomUser`, so:

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    # …
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        symmetrical=False,
        related_name='fans'
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Willem but does this not mean that each CustomUser can only have one favourite?

I want to eventually be able to return the entirety of a given users favourites via an api.

Comment: @Steve: no, a `ManyToManyField` means a `CustomUser` can have zero, one, or more `favorites`, and that `CustomUser` can have zero, one, or more `fans`: if user *A* has user *B* as `favorite`, then *B* is automatically a `fan` of *A*.